# Estimate transaction fee on BSC

Tags: ether, ethereumjs, bsc, binance-smart-chain

When I make any transactions on BSC through TrustWallet I can see "estimate" of the gass fee I need to pay. On average for 5 gwei it's around 16 cents.

Is it possible to calculate the gas fee for x Gwei given Current BNB price??
Or it's not how thats being calculated?

I would like to know rough estimate for the gas fee for say 40 Gwei when BNB is 650 dollars.

Comment: did u find a solution?

Comment: Yeah, I will answer shortly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So basically the formula is:

> Gas Limit * Gwei amount / Gwei Denomination

The total amount paid for transaction will obviously differ as it depends how much gas given function costs. But according to the formula this is how much you are WILLING to PAY at MAXIMUM if function will eat the whole gas.

For example:

```
Gas Limit = 70 000
Gwei Amount = 5
Gwei Denomination = 1 000 000 000
```

In this case Gas Limit is the Upper limit for transfer that can't be exceeded.

So there are 3 cases that can occur.

1. Transfer takes less than Gas Limit (Transaction will Succeed)
2. Transfer takes max Gas Limit (Transaction will Succeed)
3. Transfer takes more than Gas Limit (Transaction will Fail)

Given the current BNB Price which is  `376.6` (at the moment of writing)
We can roughly estimate the price of the transfer.

(Notice: You pay for how much gas is being used for transaction)

```
 Gas Limit = 70 000
 Gwei Amount = 5
 Gwei Denomination = 1 000 000 000

Case 1:  
 At maximum you WILLING to pay
 70000 * 5 / 1000000000 = 0,00035 BNB (376.6 * 0,00035 = $0,13181)

 But transaction only used say `46543` gas
 46543 * 5 / 1000000000 = 0,000232715 BNB (376.6 * 0,000232715 = $0,087640469) This is how much you would be charged

Case 2:  
 70000 * 5 / 1000000000 = 0,00035 BNB (376.6 * 0,00035 = $0,13181)

Case 3:  
 70000 * 5 / 1000000000 = 0,00035 BNB (376.6 * 0,00035 = $0,13181)
```

---

Gwei Denomination is the fixed value here.
You can operate on Gas limit and Gwei Amount to pay higher gas fee in case you want your transaction to be included earlier than others in the block for example.
Keep in mind you are not allowed to pay more than 1 BNB in gas fee using public NODE. In order to exceed that you have to use your own private node that has this limit lifted up.

https://www.investopedia.com/terms/g/gwei-ethereum.asp